# When is should/shouldn't the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) pattern be used?

Tags: database-design, eav

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a name for this database structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure)

The Entity Attribute Value (EAV) pattern usually has three columns: foreign key, attribute, and value. Attributes of data are stored in rows instead of columns. This avoids the need to add a new column to a table whenever a new attribute needs to be stored.

Though I often see the EAV pattern, I rarely feel like it was a good choice.

When is the EAV pattern the correct solution? When is it the wrong solution?

Comment: I think you are referring to the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) pattern.  As a rule it should be avoided.

Comment: Does this help? http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20763/180

Comment: @DTest Yeah I just found that too. I guess that renders my question useless.

Comment: @JustinY I closed this as a duplicate, then.  If you have a question on anything about this topic that ISN'T covered in the other Q, feel free to post a new question about it though!