# Commonly Used Acronyms by Database Administrators

Tags: terminology

What are the most commonly used acronyms among database administrators and what are their correlated meanings?

<sub>*This is for the community and those searching for meanings of commonly used terms and acronyms when working with databases, etc.*</sub>

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[**ACID**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) – Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability

**AIO** Asynchronous I/O

**BASE** - Basically Available, Soft-State, Eventually Consistent...essentially a counterpart to (though not really "opposite" of) **ACID**, this is the core principle of most NoSQL implementations.

**BI** - Business Intelligence

**BLOB** – Binary Large OBject

**CAP** – Consistency, Availability, Partition tolerance...  The three requirements of a distributed system (as they apply to a database) according to [Eric Brewer's CAP Theorem](http://www.julianbrowne.com/article/viewer/brewers-cap-theorem/).

**CDM** – Copy Data Management

**CI** – Clustered Index

**CK** – Candidate Key

**CLOB** – Character Large OBject

**CRUD** – Create, Read, Update, and Delete

**CS** – Cursor Stability - an isolation level supported by different database management systems.

**CTE** – Common Table Expression

**DB** – Database

**DBA** – Database Administrator

**DBMS** – Database Management System

**DCL** – Data Control Language

**DDL** – Data Definition Language

**DML** – Data Manipulation Language

**DMV** - Dynamic Management Views

**DR** - Disaster Recovery

[**DRBD**](http://www.drbd.org/) - Distributed Replicated Block Device

**DRDA** – Distributed Relational Database Architecture

**DRI** - Declarative Referential Integrity

**DSS** - Decision Support Systems

**DTD** – Document Type Definition

**DW** or **DWH** – Database Warehouse

**EAV** – Entity-Attribute-Value [(aka. the archenemy)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure)

**ERD** - Entity Relationship Diagram

[**ETL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) – Extract, Transform, Load

[**FDW**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fdw) - Foreign Data Wrapper (PostgreSQL)

**FK** – Foreign Key

**FLWOR** – For, Let, Where, Order, Return - an expression form used within XQuery to query XML within a database (not sure if DB2 only)

**FS** – Filesystem

**FTS** – Fulltext Search

**GBP** – Group Buffer Pool

**HA** – High Availability

**HADR** – High Availability Disaster Recovery

**HDD** – Hard Disk Drive

**ICP** – Index Condition Pushdown (MySQL)

**IOPS** – IO Per Second

**IOT** – Index Organized Table (Oracle)

**ISAM** - Indexed Sequential Access Method

**I/O** – Input/Output

**JDBC** – Java Database Connectivity

**KV** – Key/Value

**LAMP** - Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP

**LBAC** - Label Based Access Control

**LOB** – Large OBject

**LPAR** – Logical Partition

**LRU** – Last Recently Used (algorithm)

**LUN** – Logical Unit Number

**MDC** – Multidimensional Clustering Table

**MDM** – Master Data Management

[**MDX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiDimensional_eXpressions) – Multidimensional Expressions

**MED** – Management of External Data

**MQT** – Materialized Query Table (IBM DB2)

**MV** – Materialized View

[**MVCC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) – Multiversion Concurrency Control

[**NAS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) - Network Attached Storage

**NCI** – Non-clustered Index

**NF** - Normal Form (ie: 1NF, first normal form)

**ODBC** – Open Database Connectivity

**ODS** - Operational Data Store

**OLAP** – Online Analytical Processing

**OLTP** – Online Transaction Processing

**OODBMS** – Object-Oriented Database Management System

**OOM** – Out Of Memory

**ORM** – Object-Relational Mapping

**OS** – Operating System

**PK** – Primary Key

**PL/pgSQL** – Procedural Language/SQL (PostgreSQL) used for writing stored procedures. Similar to PL/SQL.

**PL/SQL** – Procedural Language/SQL (Oracle) used for writing stored procedures. Also see SQL PL.

**QPS** – Queries Per Second

**RAC** – Real Application Clusters (Oracle)

**RAID** – Redundant Array of Independent Disks

[**RBAR**](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) – Row By Agonizing Row

**RDBMS** – Relational Database Management System

**RBR** – Row-Based Replication (MySQL)

**RPO** - Recovery Point Objective - how much data you can afford to lose. If your server went down, this is the point at which you'd be able to recover the data.

**RR** – Repeatable Read - an isolation level supported by different database management systems.

**RS**

– Read Stability - an isolation level supported by different database management systems.

– Replica Set - multiple physical nodes forming a logical node with redundant data. Most commonly used in the MongoDB ecosystem

**RTO** - Recovery Time Objective - how much time it would take you to recover the data to the RPO

**SAN** – Storage Area Network

**SBR** – Statement-Based Replication (MySQL)

**SCD** – Slowly Changing Dimension

**SE** – Storage Engine (MySQL and forks)

**SEQUEL** – Structured English QUEry Language, which was IBM's precursor to SQL, which is why SQL is sometimes (often?) pronounced SEQUEL and not S.Q.L.

**SP** – Stored Procedure

**SQL** – Structured Query Language

**SQL PL** – SQL Procedure Language used for writing stored procedures. Also see PL/SQL.

**SQL/XML** – an extension of the SQL language used for querying XML.

**SSD** – Solid State Drive

**TPS*** - Transactions Per Second, a measurement of database performance.

**UAT** - User Acceptance Testing

**UDF** – User Defined Function

**UDT** – User Defined Type

**UR** – Uncommitted Read - an isolation level supported by different database management systems.

**URLT** - Update Resume; Leave Town - For those DBAs that don't bother putting together a proper recovery strategy

**XML** – eXtensible Markup Language

**XSD** – XML Schema Definition

**XSLT** – XML Stylesheet Transformation

Comment: TDS - Tabular Data Stream.