# Performance of a View with Hundreds of Left Joins

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 100+ columns, each containing a numeric value that maps to a string value in another table. When trying to create a view for the table that contains these string values, I'm getting a significant performance hit from all the joins. Given that table structures can't be changed, is there a better way to map all these strings in from the other table?

```
--MyTable--
Id  Name    attr1   attr2   attr3   ... attr200
1   First   1       2       4           2
2   Second  3       3       5           1

--StringMap--
AttrName    Value   Label
attr1       1       Small
attr1       2       Medium
attr1       3       Large
attr2       1       A
attr2       2       B
attr2       3       C
...
attr200     1       Purple
attr200     2       Blue
attr200     3       Green

select
  t.Name,
  s1.Label as attr1name,
  s2.Label as attr2name,
  s3.Label as attr3name,
  ...
  s200.Label as attr200name
from MyTable t
  left join StringMap s1 on s1.AttrName = 'attr1' and s1.Value = t.attr1
  left join StringMap s2 on s2.AttrName = 'attr2' and s2.Value = t.attr2
  left join StringMap s3 on s3.AttrName = 'attr3' and s3.Value = t.attr3
  ...
  left join StringMap s200 on s200.AttrName = 'attr200' and s200.Value = t.attr200
```

Comment: Can you [post](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) the execution plan? Do you get performance issues SELECTing the view or the view with a WHERE clause? What version and edition of SQL Server? Row counts for the view and underlying tables?

Comment: you might want to check out https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-schema-of-key-values/20763#20763

Comment: please post the table schema with indexes.  and the execution plan, as HandyD requested.

Comment: Please post a [repro] as per the link - more information is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try UnPivoting your data and then Pivoting the results:

Tables:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
Id Int,
[Name] VarChar(20),
attr1 Int,
attr2 Int,
attr3 Int,
attr200 Int
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
(1,'First',1,2,4,2),
(2,'Second',3,3,5,1)

Create Table #StringMap
(
AttrName VarChar(25),
[Value] Int,
[Label] VarChar(25)
)
Insert Into #StringMap Values
('attr1',1,'Small'),
('attr1',2,'Medium'),
('attr1',3,'Large'),
('attr2',1,'A'),
('attr2',2,'B'),
('attr2',3,'C'),
('attr200',1,'Purple'),
('attr200',2,'Blue'),
('attr200',3,'Green')
```

Query uses CTEs to UnPivot your table to have a single join to your StringMap table.  It then Pivots back the results

```
;With cte As
(
  Select 
        id, [name], attr, vals 
  From #tbl
  UnPivot
    (
      vals
      For attr IN (attr1, attr2, attr3, attr200)
    ) As u
  ), cte1 As
(
  Select cte.id, cte.[Name], cte.attr, s.[Label] 
  From cte 
  Inner Join #StringMap s 
    On s.[Value] = cte.vals And s.AttrName = cte.attr
)
Select [Name] As [Name],
       [attr1], [attr2], [attr3], [attr200]
From 
(Select [Name], [Label], attr From cte1) As src
Pivot
(
Max(Label) For attr IN ([attr1], [attr2], [attr3], [attr200])

) As piv
```

Result:

```
Name    attr1   attr2   attr3   attr200
First   Small   B       NULL    Blue
Second  Large   C       NULL    Purple
```

Note:
With so many columns, you'll want to search the site for using dynamic Pivots Such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: I was thinking of something like this but the scale of it makes me think that the pivot/unpivot would perform worse (testing needed, of course) than the original.  I was thinking that perhaps a columnstore index might help as well.    But without the original execution plan and DDL I can't really say.