# Should I use a single column with many dimensions with columnar data?

Tags: database-design, columnstore

I'm using Apache Iceberg which performs queries on Parquet files. The data saves a lot of types of events and their respective numeric values. I'm hesitating whether it's more efficient to have one column for event type or have a column for each event.

Single event type column:
[image]

**VS**
Dedicated column for each event type:
[image]

I'm wondering though if I want to run a `group by` query for `col1`, `col2` by some `event_type` in theory if there was a dedicated column for that `event_type` then the db would have to scan less data as opposed to having scan more data when all event types are stored in a single column.

What is the best practice when designing schemas for such data in columnar data storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm hesitating whether it's more efficient to have one column for event type or have a column for each event.

A column for each event type (since they appear to be different kinds of attributes) would probably make the most sense here. A single column for all event types smells like the [Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) Anti-Pattern](https://cedanet.com.au/antipatterns/eav.php).

The EAV anti-pattern is generally inefficient for querying, can conflict data types, and makes aggregative queries more difficult to implement. It also hurts maintainability and data integrity.

Aside from that, different database systems offer different features for indexing and compression of columnar data. Mixing different / unrelated data into the same column will hurt the maximum potential one can gain from such features.

Further reading on the EAV anti-pattern:

1. [Is there a name for this database schema of key values?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20763/150011)
2. [EAV - in an ecommerce case, is it really an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347290/eav-in-an-ecommerce-case-is-it-really-an-anti-pattern)
3. [Database Modelization Anti-Patterns](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/03/database-modelization-anti-patterns/#entity-attribute-values)

Comment: The best way to demonstrate the frailties of the EAV model is the image [here](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html) - I find it hilarious! :-)